# Trying to properly set up query for match of 2 csv files got stuck

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Here's an example of what the data looks like on each csv.

**inventory.csv**

```
ID, payment, Receipt#                                 
90006, VISA, jk73kl_                          
90006, VISA, null
```

**inventory.csv**

```
INFO, VIEWS, DATE
9006_Produce_Banana_jk73kl__, 0, 10-13-20
9006_Produce_Banana, 0, 10-13-20
```

I am having trouble with my where, I need to search both forms and if there is a matching receipt number pull them out and combine the two rows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] ourDataSheet = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../OurData.csv");
            string[] theirDataSheet = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../TheirData.csv");
            string ourDataHeaders = ourDataSheet[0];
            string theirDataHeaders = theirDataSheet[0];
            

            IEnumerable<string> TrackingQuery =
                from ourData in ourDataSheet
                let ourDataFields = ourData.Split(',')
                from theirData in theirDataSheet
                let theirDataFields = theirData.Split(',')
                where theirDataFields[0].EndsWith(ourDataFields[2])
                select ourDataFields[0] + "," + ourDataFields[1] + "," + ourDataFields[2] + "," + theirDataFields[0] + "," + theirDataFields[0] + "," + theirDataFields[1] + "," + theirDataFields[2] + "," + theirDataFields[3];

            OutPutResults(TrackingQuery);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void OutPutResults(IEnumerable<string> query)
        {
            foreach(string item in query)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
               Console.Read();
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would recommend that you use a third-party package like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and do something like the following

```
public class Sale
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
    [Name("Recipt#")]
    public string Recipt { get; set; }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public string INFO { get; set; }
    public string VIEWS { get; set; }
    public string DATE { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Sale> sales;
IEnumerable<Inventory> inventory;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"../../OurData.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    sales = csv.GetRecords<Sale>();
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"../../TheirData.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    inventory = csv.GetRecords<Inventory>();
}

var results = sales.Where(s => inventory.Any(i => i.INFO.EndsWith(s.Recipt)));
```

Comment: in my inventory.csv there or null and blank values for the 3rd col. how should i handle a blank 3rd column? should i run inventory results through a function to pull out all rows with blank or 3rd column then run it through. add an additional step to the results function or set class get set to have a default?